# Illegal string offset 'qty' Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, string, offset

I have a problem with Illegal string offset 'qty' using wordpress and I don't know how to fix it.

> Illegal string offset 'qty'
>   public_html/wp-content/themes/freelancersvalley/includes/aecore/payments.php on line 70

Code:

```
function ae_user_package_info($user_ID) {
    if (!$user_ID) return;
    global $ae_post_factory;
    $ae_pack = $ae_post_factory->get('pack');
    $packs = $ae_pack->fetch();
    $orders = AE_Payment::get_current_order($user_ID);
    $package_data = AE_Package::get_package_data($user_ID);
    foreach ($packs as $package) {
        $sku = $package->sku;
        if (isset($package_data[$sku]) && $package_data[$sku]['qty'] > 0) {
            if( $package->post_type == 'pack'){
                $order = get_post($orders[$sku]);
                if (!$order || is_wp_error($order) || !in_array($order->post_status, array('publish', 'pending'))) continue;
                    /**
                    * print text when company has job left in package
                    */
                    ?>
                    <p>
```

Where is the mistake?

Comment: `print_r($package_data);` is qty in there?

Answer (score 0):

Your error means that `$package_data[$sku]` is a string and not an array (as you are expecting.

The offset of `a` in `stackoverflow` is `2` (because `s` is 0 and `t` is `1`).

To fix this issue, you need to ensure that `$package_data[$sku]` is an array AND that it contains a key called `qty`.

I'm not sure if it will actually "fix" your issue, but you can avoid the error if you write: `isset($package_data[$sku]['qty'])` instead of `isset($package_data[$sku])`

Comment: Thanks mickmackusa, i write what you said, be have new problem
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home/frlley/domains/freelancersvalley.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/freelanceersvalley/includes/aecore/payments.php on line 72

Comment: Make sure you have a closing `)` for every opening `(` in the line before the `{`.

Comment: Warning solved! I made a mistake writing your code :)

Comment: As for solving the fundamental issue, you'll need to start debugging with some well placed check points and print variables to screen.  I'm not a Wordpress guy, so I'll wish you luck.